# Why is my 'npm start' script resulting in the error: 'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-start

while giving command- npm start
the result goes with this and I am not able to get the local host ip

> git-test@1.0.0 start
> run npm lite

'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

also added-
"scripts": {
"start": "run npm lite",
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1",
"lite":"lite-server"
},
in package.json file, but;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `npm run lite`, not `run npm lite`.

Comment: `run npm lite` is invalid, you should use `npm run lite`

Answer (score 0):

try `npm install` then `npm start`